# Xcode 4.3 crashes when using LLDB

Tags: xcode, crash, lldb

Since installing xcode 4.3 (from the app store), Xcode crashes when I try to run a few of my apps with the debugger set to LLDB. GDB works fine.

I've already tried reinstalling iTunes and removing all traces of xcode and reinstalling that. I've also tried removing the .xib files and re-adding them to the project.

Any help would be great :)

Here is some of the report that is generated:

> Process:         Xcode [2102] Path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier:
>   com.apple.dt.Xcode Version:         4.3.2 (1177) Code Type:
>   X86-64 (Native)
>
> Date/Time:       2012-05-05 11:02:34.865 +1000 OS Version:      Mac OS
>   X 10.7.3 (11D50b) Report Version:  9
>
> Interval Since Last Report:          2063 sec Crashes Since Last
>   Report:           7 Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  882 sec
>   Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   7
>
> Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 4E2002 UNCAUGHT
>   EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Couldn't load plug-in
>   'com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB' while firing fault for extension
>   'Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Debugger.LLDB' UserInfo: {
>       NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 \"Loading a plug-in failed.\" UserInfo=0x402a89c20
>   {DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB,
>   DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite
>   plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled.,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed.,
>   NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in
>   \U201ccom.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB\U201d at path
>   \U201c/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin\U201d
>   could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins
>   may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x4003c62e0 \"The bundle
>   \U201cDebuggerLLDB\U201d couldn\U2019t be loaded because it is damaged
>   or missing necessary resources.\"}"; } Hints: None Backtrace:   0 
>   0x00007fff945fcfaa __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)   1 
>   0x00007fff8c9add5e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)   2 
>   0x000000010f1b207f -[DVTExtension _fireExtensionFault] (in
>   DVTFoundation)   3  0x000000010f22c666
>   __DVTDispatchSync_block_invoke_0 (in DVTFoundation)   4  0x00007fff90a53aad _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke (in
>   libdispatch.dylib)   5  0x000000010f22c483 DVTDispatchSync (in
>   DVTFoundation)   6  0x000000010f22c297 DVTSyncPerformBlock (in
>   DVTFoundation)   7  0x000000010f18e69b -[DVTDispatchLock
>   performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)   8  0x000000010f1b1e32
>   -[DVTExtension _valueForKey:inParameterData:usingSchema:] (in DVTFoundation)   9  0x000000010f1b1d6f -[DVTExtension valueForKey:]
>   (in DVTFoundation)  10  0x0000000116707322 -[DBGLLDBDebugLocalService
>   operationWorkerWithLaunchSession:error:] (in DebuggerLLDBService)  11 
>   0x0000000116cc10b8 (in IDEiPhoneSupport)  12  0x000000010f85f9d3
>   -[IDERunDestination runOperationForLaunchSession:error:] (in IDEFoundation)  13  0x000000010f85e690 -[IDELaunchSchemeAction
>   runOperationForExecutionEnvironment:withBuildOperation:buildParameters:buildableProductDirectories:runDestination:outError:]
>   (in IDEFoundation)  14  0x000000010f85a5d0 -[IDEScheme
>   _executionOperationForExecutionEnvironment:build:onlyBuild:buildPurpose:buildCommand:schemeCommand:overridingProperties:destination:buildLog:filePath:error:testCallbackBlock:]
>   (in IDEFoundation)  15  0x000000010f85dc0b -[IDEScheme
>   runWithExecutionContext:buildIfNeeded:onlyBuild:destination:overridingProperties:commandName:error:]
>   (in IDEFoundation)  16  0x000000010fc8cdfc -[IDEWorkspaceTabController
>   _actuallyPerformContextTask:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:completionBlock:]
>   (in IDEKit)  17  0x000000010fd354aa __107-[IDEWorkspaceTabController
>   _performContextTask:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_0
>   (in IDEKit)  18  0x000000010fc8cab3 -[IDEWorkspaceTabController
>   _performContextTask:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:completionBlock:]
>   (in IDEKit)  19  0x000000010fd3578e __101-[IDEWorkspaceTabController
>   _performDebuggableContextTask:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:]_block_invoke_0
>   (in IDEKit)  20  0x00000001109e62e8 -[DVTDeveloperModeAlertHelper
>   _askToEnableDeveloperModeIfNecessary] (in DVTDeveloperModeHelper)  21  0x000000010fcb85aa -[IDEWorkspaceTabController
>   _performDebuggableContextTask:command:commandName:buildCommand:filePath:]
>   (in IDEKit)  22  0x000000010fcb83e5 -[IDEWorkspaceTabController
>   runActiveRunContext:] (in IDEKit)  23  0x00007fff945ec75d -[NSObject
>   performSelector:withObject:] (in CoreFoundation)  24 
>   0x00007fff913f1cb2 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit) 
>   25  0x000000010f4838b6 -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in
>   DVTKit)  26  0x000000010fbd2096 -[IDEApplication sendAction:to:from:]
>   (in IDEKit)  27  0x00007fff945ec75d -[NSObject
>   performSelector:withObject:] (in CoreFoundation)  28 
>   0x00007fff913f1cb2 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit) 
>   29  0x000000010f4838b6 -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in
>   DVTKit)  30  0x000000010fbd2096 -[IDEApplication sendAction:to:from:]
>   (in IDEKit)  31  0x000000010f53ea10 -[DVTDelayedMenuButtonCell
>   trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] (in DVTKit)  32 
>   0x00007fff913efbde -[NSControl mouseDown:] (in AppKit)  33 
>   0x00007fff913ba6e0 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] (in AppKit)  34 
>   0x00007fff9135316d -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)  35 
>   0x000000010fbcddd1 -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)  36 
>   0x00007fff912e91f2 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)  37 
>   0x00007fff91567b88 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)  38 
>   0x000000010f188eec (in Xcode)   Performing
>   @selector(performRunAction:) from sender
>   IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton 0x401e634a0 objc[2102]: garbage
>   collection is ON abort() called

Comment: Checkout the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905378/xcode-4-3-4-4-crashes-with-breakpoints-using-lldb-breakpoints-useless-with-gdb/11961253?iemail=1#11961253).  It worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi I have the same problem and I reported to Apple, they told me is a bug and they know about it , my only way around is to change the compiler to GDB all the time, until Apple fix the bug.

Answer (score 5):

I have solve the problem as bellow:may be is useful for you.I try to execute the lldb command in terminal, it got the result like that the my lldb need the python 2.7.but before,when i install the clang,the python version changed to 2.6,so i reinstall the python 2.7.my lldb worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you upgraded to Xcode 4.6.1?  If so then look for /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 if there is no 2.7 reinstall Python. There is a installer at Python.org for MAC. Btw if you happen to see Current and not 2.7 remove the folder called Current.  I had the LLDB problem and this is what I've done and everything worked well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem when Python was installed with homebrew.

I just did this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
```

And problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Still isn't working for me as of Mountain Lion (10.8.2), Xcode 4.5.1, I've tried deleting and reinstalling to no avail. This isn't a huge deal to me right now as I'm still learning (did the Stanford course & doing the Big Nerd Ranch book right now) however I imagine once I start doing some team work that people won't appreciate me changing the Product Scheme over from LLDB to GDB just so I can run the simulator.